# Loading Avro into BigQuery via the Spark Connector

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, avro

From what I've seen in these example, it's only do-able via Gson. Is it possible to directly load Avro objects into a BigQuery table via the Spark Connector? Converting from Avro to BigQuery Json becomes a pain when the avro specification starts going beyond simple primitive values. (e.g. Unions)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not through Spark Connector, but BigQuery supports loading AVRO files directly: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#loading_avro_files

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work. However, since Google uses the Avro C++ library, there will most likely be caveats which I appear to already be running into. Do you know if this is documented anywhere? Most of my columns are primitive types with some unions. I am also using the Snappy compression format.

Comment: I am not sure which caveats you are running into, but in general primitive types and Snappy compression are all supported. For concrete problems, it is the best to file bugs at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: All Avro data types are supported by the C++ library and also in BQ (with some conversions, e.g. fixed to bytes). You're correct that data blocks compressed using snappy is not supported. Deflate is the only codec supported by the C++ library.

Comment: Thanks @HuaZhang. I can see the support outlined here. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1748.